# Rooting failed, superSU remains

Tags: rooting, unrooting, superuser, kingo, samsung-galaxy-core-2

I tried to root my Galaxy Core 2 Duos using Kingo root, which installed SuperSU. Unfortunately rooting failed all of a sudden, but still SuperSU remains.

How can I remove SuperSU from my device?

Answer (score 0):

for Root your Device, i think after using KingoRoot, you need Install Latest version of `SuperSu`then, Root access is Successfully work.

and, for Delete ;

Use Full Wipe, or Install new rom.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save /SDcard stuff (Photo/Video/otherstuff)
2. Open Kies - Do "firmware upgrade/wipe) clears SU

Careful with samsung ; they dont like to be rooted. in fact the worst brand to IMO

Answer (score 0):

You should simply just be able to uninstall SuperSU as you would any app via your apps viewer. If I were you I would avoid using KingoRoot, I have heard some poor rumors about it. Try Re-rooting the device using something like towelroot, afterwords you would then install SuperSU from the appstore, allowing you to give apps superuser permission.